# Unable to fetch data from table

Tags: php, html

I am testing a form that asks for a users email and then sends him his name,surname and cellphone number. Now everything is working. It selects the user depending on the email entered. It sends the email.

The only issue I am having is how do I insert the data from the table into the email thats sending to him?

```
Eg.$mail->Body     = "Your company details are: " Name,Surname,Cellphone;
```

thats the issue I am currently facing. My full code is below.

I am still quite new at PHP so if this is a general/common error, then I apologise.

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="****"; // Mysql password
$db_name="Username"; // Database name
$tbl_name="Name"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,  $username,  $password, $db_name);

// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['user_name'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Name='$username'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count > 0)
{

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "****"; // SMTP server                     // enables SMTP debug information
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "****"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "****"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "****";        // SMTP account password
$mail->From = "Test";
$mail->FromName = "Test";

$mail->AddAddress($username, "");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  = 'Out Of Office Password';
$mail->Body     = "Your Out Of Office password: ";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';
}

}
```

?>

The form:

```
<center>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Information</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="check-user.php" method="POST">
  <h3>User Information</h3>

  Email: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Info">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</center>
```

Comment: `mysql` !== `mysqli`

Comment: @Niklesh i fixed them all i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your connection valid

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,  $username,  $password, $db_name)
// if u get connection valid message delete this if statement this is just for testing your connection
if ($conn) {
   echo 'connection valid';
} else {
   echo 'connection invalid ' . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

And u don't need this

```
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysqli_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysqli_error());
echo "Connected to Database<br />";
```

Change this line

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

And this one

```
if ($count > 0) {
```

And because u new to php, i think u need atleast learn how to connect to database, check for error_reporting, get/update/insert/delete data into database.

And my opinion is if u are starting to learn use **`PDO with prepared statements`** because it safe. This `mysqli` without escaping will get u trouble with security.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="Username"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Name"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse. 
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Define $username 
    $username = $_POST['user_name']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Name='$username'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

    if ($count > 0 )
    { 

    // get data from user
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; 

    $mail = new PHPMailer; 

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP 
    $mail->Host = "****"; // SMTP server // enables SMTP debug information 
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication 
    $mail->Host = "****"; // sets the SMTP server 
    $mail->Port = 587; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server 
    $mail->Username = "****"; // SMTP account username 
    $mail->Password = "****"; // SMTP account password 
    $mail->From = "Test"; 
    $mail->FromName = "Test"; 

    $mail->AddAddress($username, ""); 

    $mail->isHTML(true); 

    $mail->Subject = 'Your Company Details'; 
    $mail->Body = "Your company details are: Name: = " . $data['Name'] . ", Surname: " . $data['Surname'] . ", Cellphone: " . $data['Cellphone']; 

    if(!$mail->Send())
    { 
        echo 'Message could not be sent.'; 
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
        exit(); 
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';
    } 

} 

ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Comment: ok it comes back valid but now it says my email is unsuccessful in sending

Comment: @Mario i did it and now it shows blank. No error/success. Nothing

Comment: Remove `ob_start():` and `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: i did. Still just blank page.

Comment: @Mario i edited my code on the question. Is that all correct?

Comment: can u post your `<form>` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137754/discussion-between-mario-and-redz).